# Able to suggest edits despite being edit-banned

Tags: bug, status-review, suggested-edits

([This question was migrated](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10126/able-to-suggest-edits-despite-being-edit-banned) from the [Worldbuilding Meta](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com))

---

Recently, I've been working on the tag wikis over on [Worldbuilding](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com). I keep a lot of tabs open when working on projects like this.[image: a lot of tabs]

After a few rejects, I got auto-banned. Whether or not some of those rejects should have happened at all is another thing entirely, but it is what it is now.

The problem is, I am still able to suggest edits. [Take a look at my suggestion history](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/98654/the-commander?tab=activity&sort=suggestions). You'll see a gap in between my edit waves, after I racked up my fifth reject. Approvals to the recent edits show that

However, as a consequence of the powers of Way Too Many Tabs, I still had some half-done edit suggestions. I completed and submitted these, even though a ban is in place.

Comment: Looks like an unintended consequence of [this feature change](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/423305/2157772). I think they incorrectly changed it to accept an edit *always* even if the user wouldn't be allowed to suggest an edit, whether it's because the edit queue is full or another cause such as the user being banned from suggesting edits.

Comment: For that matter, I wonder if suspended users might also be able to submit edits from open tabs.

Comment: @Laurel most likely, ask a mod to suspend you and let's see! :-D

Comment: @ShadowTheSpringWizard As a mod, I can suspend myself just fine thank you very much :p

Comment: I did some testing yesterday on Super User and was correctly blocked from suggesting an edit to a sixth post after opening the edit forms for 6 posts and submitting edits to the first five. So that casts my prior theory into doubt - but that could be a separate check from others.

Comment: I should note that I am unsure if it was an edit ban in the first place; I was unable to go to the edit pages(and the buttons to edit were gone), but I was able to edit about an hour later. That being said, my other edits that went through WERE accepted, so the ratio might have gone above the threshold.

Comment: I would be very surprised if this has anything to do with the [suggested edit queue update](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/398145/allow-edits-which-have-already-started-even-when-queue-is-full/423305#423305) we rolled out (wouldn't be the first time I was surprised tho).   We only added the ability to bypass the queue if it’s full and if it wasn’t when you started your edit.  Passing the queue limit check does not remove the other checks that occur for any suggested edit.  I'd say slim possibility it's a regression, but worth investigating anyway.